# Linker Error - typedef struct

Tags: c, linker-errors

I have a compiling/linking error as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_memory_table", referenced from:
_initialize in main.o

linker command failed with exit code 1
```

The problem may be in the .h file below. Have I done anything wrong with my typedef structs? The main.c simply calls initialize(). The initialize() fuction is below.  For brevity, I have taken out all of the #define macros. Main is included further down the code.

Thanks.

```
//globals.h
#ifndef memory_manager_globals_h
#define memory_manager_globals_h

/******** Memory Table Entry Data Structure**********/
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t block_address;
    uint32_t next_free_block;

}mem_table_entry_t;

/******** Memory Table Data Structure**********/
typedef struct
{
    mem_table_entry_t two_kib[8];
    mem_table_entry_t one_kib[16];
    mem_table_entry_t half_kib[32];
    mem_table_entry_t quarter_kib[64];
    mem_table_entry_t eighth_kib[128];

}mem_table_t;

extern mem_table_t memory_table;

#endif
```

...

```
//MAIN.C
#include <stdio.h>
#include "globals.h"


void initialize(void)
{

    int block_count = 0;            //
    uint32_t dynamic_address = HEAP_START;

    while(block_count <= INITIALIZE_BLOCK_COUNT)
    {
        if((block_count >= TWO_KIB_LO) && (block_count < TWO_KIB_HI))
        {
            memory_table.two_kib[block_count].block_address = HEAP_START;
        dynamic_address = dynamic_address + 0x800;

        memory_table.two_kib[block_count].next_free_block = dynamic_address;
        block_count++;
    }
...
```

[SOLVED] The correct format of the .h file should be as follows:

```
/******** Memory Table Entry Data Structure**********/
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t block_address;
    uint32_t next_free_block;

}mem_table_entry_t;


/******** Memory Table Data Structure**********/
typedef struct
{
    mem_table_entry_t two_kib[8];
    mem_table_entry_t one_kib[16];
    mem_table_entry_t half_kib[32];
    mem_table_entry_t quarter_kib[64];
    mem_table_entry_t eighth_kib[128];

}mem_table_t;

    mem_table_t memory_table;

    extern mem_table_t memory_table;
```

Comment: And now show the file with the **definition** of `mem_table`.

Comment: No that is wrong! A header should never have _definitions_ (except `inline` functions, but that is a different subject)! A good C book will detail this much better than pssible here - sorry, we are no tutoring service.

Comment: `mem_table_t memory_table;` should *not* be in the header, but in any .c includeing the header.

Comment: @Olaf - Ok, fair enough. My prof has only insisted that there be no code in a header file. I will dig around and find some tips on header etiquette. Thanks.

Comment: @Darrell He should first have clarified basic terms like _definition_ and _declaration_ (and theri differences). "no code" is correct in a general ("nothing which directly generates data into the program file") sense, but likely too unclear for a beginner's course. But I know that many C teachers have problems with the nomenclature themselves. Hint: Learn their differences and ask you prof to explain the terms. Compare with what you found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a definition of `memory_table`. The `extern` line is a declaration, not a definition.

Add this line to your C file to fix the linking problem:

```
mem_table_t memory_table;
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I see. Silly mistake. Thankyou very much.